# MYSQL 8 Hours Time out Problem

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL 5.0 and Tomcat 5.5.
After 8 hours , MYSQL closes by default closes all idle connections and so I am getting an SQL Exception .Any solution to this problem

Answer (score 7):

Which connection pool are you using? Most allow a heartbeat command to be executed periodically to keep connections from idling out.

EDIT: Looking at the [DBCP configuration page](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html), I think you should set an appropriate (cheap) `validationQuery`. You could then either tell DBCP to test this when potentially evicting idle connections (`testWhileIdle`) or tell it to test just before returning the connection (`testOnBorrow`). The first would (hopefully!) keep your idle connections alive; the second wouldn't, but wouldn't return you broken connections (i.e. if would create a new one if necessary).

Comment: Or to test the connection before using it, and if it's been killed, create a fresh one.

Comment: Basically I am using OpenCMS, a content Management System, Which Uses MYSQL and Tomcat.It uses DBCP connection Pooling mechanism

Comment: Brilliant answer @Jon. Out of interest, which would you recommend out of these two methods?

Comment: @SteveChambers: I'm afraid I don't have nearly enough recent experience to make an educated recommendation.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Think I'll go for `testOnBorrow` for now as it seems to be completely independent of the `wait_timeout` value. The only thing that slightly concerns me is whether it might have any effect on performance but hopefully this won't be an issue. (Another solution I also considered was `autoReconnect=true` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594583/mysql-connection-timeout#2595293) but have now discounted this as it isn't recommended by [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html#idm140446220006144).)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you keep the connections alive while they are idle? I am no expert on mySql, but in the databases I have been working with it's considered good practice to keep the connection open only while it's needed, and then close it.

Comment: Where individual request speed is of the essence (e.g. OLTP where individual requests may often be frequent and small and consumers browse away if the page is slow) a pool holds up to a fixed number of connections (protecting the DB from infinite connections) and keeps them open as long as possible to avoid paying connection startup costs. Without a pool, or when request startup is a minor part of your per-operation cost (e.g. OLAP), one might not bother with a pool in which case yes make sure you close the connections. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to increase the timeout but I guess there should be a setting.. Why don't you create the connection when you need it, and close it after using it other than depending on a created connection?

Comment: wait_timeout , will increse the time, but i dont think so, it would be the feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, by default an open connection (often waiting in a connection pool) will be closed after 8 hours of inactivity. You can change this time from 8 hours by configuring the wait_timeout variable either in your my.cnf or on our mysql command line

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a few years ago, but I feel that it's good to have the correct answer. i had the same issue, to solve I had to play with the configuration a little bit. here is what works for me. Go on https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html for more info. The code below took care of everything. There is way to optimize the values but I will take care of these later.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/database" 
               auth="Container" 
               type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" 
               maxIdle="30" 
               maxWait="10000"
          username="username" password="password" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql:///"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          testOnReturn="false"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="30000"`enter code here`
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
          minIdle="10" `enter code here`
          initialSize="10"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          logAbandoned="true"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" 
          jmxEnabled="true"         
           />
```