# Database sleeping and causing exception

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection, mariadb

When I don't make any database queries for some time I think it must sleep - if you then call it an exception is thrown;

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0bytes from 4
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:136)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MySQLStatement.java:264)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:288)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLStatement.java:317)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLPreparedStatement.java:156)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
        at com.swifte.database.DBFactory.updateTimeForUser(DBFactory.java:302)
        at com.swifte.database.DBFactory.addInsertToDB(DBFactory.java:275)
        at com.swifte.service.ExposedFunctions.login(ExposedFunctions.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening - I have tried adding the auto connect property to the URL but it still seems to occur

Thanks

Comment: Hi Biscuit, did you find a solution or any more information on this phenomenon ?

Comment: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-348

Comment: When you get that exception, reconnect.  It could be a timeout; it could be a network glitch.

Answer (score 2):

This may be stretching your memory but could

> for some time

have been 8+ hours? If so, likely to be the [MySQL inactivity timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout), which disconnects after 28800 seconds. I hit this problem recently and found a few SO questions about it - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824320/mysql-8-hours-time-out-problem#824324) contained the best simple nuggets for solving the problem. In short, would suggest adding a `validationQuery` of `SELECT 1` and setting `testOnBorrow = true` in the DBCP connection pool properties.