# MariaDB : Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream

Tags: java, mysql, database, mariadb, database-performance

Does anyone knows how to solve the problem "Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4."
I use MariaDB 10.1.14.
The problem arrives ramdomly, but particularly in the 2 following situations.
- The server is busy because too many requests have been send in a little time.
- The server has not been use for 15 minutes, and someone refreshes a page.
Then MariaDB is crashed and we have to restart it.

Best regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database sleeping and causing exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595809/database-sleeping-and-causing-exception)

Comment: See also: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-348

Comment: I couldn't find any solution either. Does anyone have an idea?